# Почему не сработало правило?

Tags: jquery

```
alert(result); // выводит GH_1

$('#'+result).remove(); // Не удаляет элемент на странице с id="GH_1"
```

Comment: Дык, мы ж не телепаты. Проблема явно [не в этих двух строчках][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/tVugf/

Comment: Возможно, на вашей странице оказалось несколько элементов с одним и тем же id.

Comment: Ваш код заключен в конструкцию $(document).ready(function(){}) ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
do
{
    $('#'+result).remove();
}
while ($('#'+result).length>0)
```

[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/tVugf/2/)

еще один вариант, который, как ни странно, но работает:

```
var result = 'GH_1';
$('[id="'+result+'"]').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[пример2](http://jsfiddle.net/tVugf/3/)

Comment: Костыль. Лучше объяснить разницу между #id и .class, заменить идентификатор на класс и работать с классом.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, я еще до конца не уверен, та ли ошибка у автора вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что при выборке данных jQuery может вернуть вам несколько объектов соответствующих условию выборки поэтому лучше делать так:

```
$('#'+result).each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Update:

Оказывается если выбирать элементы по id то jQuery вернет только первый элемент который обнаружит, поэтому код который я написал не решит проблему. Нужно исправлять проблему с дублированием id на странице.

Comment: Но лучше избегать ситуаций в которых на странице повторяются id элементов.

Comment: зато мой способ будет работать :) Но от дубликатов id надо избавляться )

Comment: да вы правы )

Comment: кстати, если взять селектор: `$('[id="'+result+'"]')` - то все id найдет )